# nightwatch test fails with multiple click events in sequence

Tags: selenium, nightwatch

When running a nightwatch.js test on a browser with a checkbox that 
is not visible using the following code.

```
browser.moveToElement('input[id="2verificationYes"]')
.click('input[id="2verificationYes"]')
```

I get the following error :

```
An error occurred while running .click() command on ,input[id="2verificationYes"]>: unknown error: Element `element` is not clickable at point (111, 701). Other element would receive the click: `otherElement`

at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:64:7)
```

I am using 
nightwatch v.1.0.19, chromedriver ^2.43.0, geckodriver ^1.16.2, selenium-server ^3.14.0

I have tried using the callback functions with each call but the result is the same.  Tried to research how to scroll to an element in nightwatch, but the api's don't have that.  It is my understanding the the moveToElement function is supposed to scroll to the element.

Answer (score 0):

For me moveToElement is working good. I  believe you are seeing error because you forgot to mentioned the **Xoffset** and **Yoffset**. 
Try my below work around and let  me know:

browser.moveToElement('input[id="2verificationYes"]'**,Xoffset,Yoffset**)
.click('input[id="2verificationYes"]')

for your reference: [search 'moveToElement' here](https://nightwatchjs.org/api)

Can you try giving '0' and let me know:

browser.moveToElement('input[id="2verificationYes"]'**,0,0**)
.click('input[id="2verificationYes"]')

Same time try giving little wait time to narrow down the issue. Good luck